# Exchange Management Shell Default Exchange Server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

My question is whether or not there is a way to specify the default Exchange Server Connection in ExchangeShell and how I could configure such.  Currently ExchangeShell attempts to connect to the nearest server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the properties of the EMS icon, it should show a command line of:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto

Change that Connect-ExchangeServer -auto to:

Connect-ExchangeServer -ServerFQDN "servername.domain.com"

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the EMS shortcut. At the end of the Target box you'll find this:

```
... ;Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
```

Replace '-auto' with your Server name.

```
... ;Connect-ExchangeServer ServerFqdn
```

The `Connect-ExchangeServer` function is defined in the $exbin\ConnectFunctions.ps1 which is loaded by startup script defined in the EMS shortcut (RemoteExchange.ps1)